# ng-change doesn't evaluate function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Problem : ng-change directive doesn't evaluate a function

Description:

```
  <input class="cmn-tgl" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="user.habits.early_riser" ng-change="updateUserDetails()">
```

input element for html defined above is a toggle switch.

Also, Javascript framework used is AngularJS
......HTML Snippet.....

```
<div controller1>
      <div contorller2>
         <input....>  
      </div>
</div>
```

.....Controller Snippet....

```
angular.controller1 {
      $scope.user=*object*
  }

angular.controller2 {
   $scope.updateUserDetails = function() {
      something happens here
  }    
}
```

here is the structure of the HTML code.

When the switch toggles..model is updated. but ng-change doesn't evaluates 
the function...

instead if ng-change expression is asked to evaluate this :

```
ng-change="user.habits.late_night=!user.habits.early_riser"
```

this works changes in the model are evident

..any idea why

Comment: Your code is completely invalid, but assuming updateUserDetails is a function, exposed on the scope, the syntax is `ng-change="updateUserDetails()"` (with parentheses).

Comment: There are so many basic javascript syntactical mistakes.. I think you should correct them first,,

Comment: Also it should be `$scope.updateUserDetails = function() { ..` I highly recommend you to check this -> https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: I wrote this post in a haste, anyways I have edited the post, @JBNizet

Comment: And it's still completely invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try ng-click instead of ng-change for the input?

Comment: thanks, I have tried it all, since there were couple of mistakes in the post earlier, but after revision, post is describes the problem accurately.